# Problema de Navegacion | Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, activity, radiobutton, radiogroup

he intentado ingresar a un activity mediante un radiogroup -> radio button y luego tocar un botón, el problema era que no me llevaba al activity que quería y se cerraba la app, creí que era error de eso, pero cuando intente solo ir mediante un botón vi que tampoco funcionaba y pasaba a lo mismo. Sabrán alguna solución? se las agradecería, cuando le di al logcat me dio todo esto, soy novato y pues la verdad no le entendí del todo, gracias de antemano.

[image: Es es lo que me dio de error si mal no estoy]
[image: Este es el activity al que quiero ir]
[image: Este es donde están los radio button y el boton que me tendria que llevar a al activity de alumnos]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los errores y el codigo que lo provoca deben ir como texto...

Comment: No se ve el error completo, acostúmbralo agregar como texto en tu pregunta, tambièn el còdigo que realiza al tocar un botón